# Can SFINAE not prevent ambiguous operator overloads?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, c++14, sfinae

I thought the following code would compile because conflicting overloads are SFINAEd away. But the compiler (GCC) says: `void Foo<X>::bar(Xd) const' cannot be overloaded`. Is there an easy to way to fix it, or would I have to specialize the whole of `Foo`?

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A{};

template<typename X>
struct Foo {
    template<typename Xd=X, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<Xd>::value>>
    void bar() const {
    }

    template<typename Xd=X, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<Xd,A>::value>>
    void bar() const {
    }
};

int main(){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) for std::enable_if:

> A common mistake is to declare two function templates that differ only
>   in their default template arguments. This does not work because the
>   declarations are treated as redeclarations of the same function
>   template (default template arguments are not accounted for in function
>   template equivalence).

```
/*** WRONG ***/
struct T {
    enum { int_t,float_t } m_type;
    template <typename Integer,
              typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>
    >
    T(Integer) : m_type(int_t) {}

    template <typename Floating,
              typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value>
    >
    T(Floating) : m_type(float_t) {} // error: treated as redefinition
};


/* RIGHT */   
struct T {
    enum { int_t,float_t } m_type;
    template <typename Integer,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, int> = 0
    >
    T(Integer) : m_type(int_t) {}

    template <typename Floating,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value, int> = 0
    >
    T(Floating) : m_type(float_t) {} // OK
};
```